# backgroundworker_progresschanged not doing anything

Tags: c#, text, label, backgroundworker

I have a program where I want to check the existing internal IP of the users machine and then the new Internal IP once it connects to a VPN. I check if the user's IP has changed with a background worker. This is the following code I have:

```
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();


        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (Connection.CheckForInternetConnection()) //Makes sure an internet connection is available
            {
                CurrentInternalIP = GetIPAddress(); //Regularly retrieve the current IP so we can compare against the old IP
                if (CurrentInternalIP != OldInternalIP) //Compare the current IP address with the old one
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("IP has changed");//Make sure the event is working correctly
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Connected to VPN.";
        }
```

Now the worker_DoWork event is working correctly. However the worker_ProgressChanged event isn't changing the text of the label once the IP in the worker_DoWork event is changed. I initially had my code to change the text of the label in my worker_DoWork event, however this gave me an error because I was accessing a label other than the UI it was created on - so this isn't possible. I appreciate any help.

Comment: `worker.ReportProgress(...)`  Your code is doing the "work" so only you can know what the progress is and when to report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into your code, you have assigned `DoWork` event of the worker to the `worker_DoWork` EventHandler, But you have not assigned the `ProgressChanged` so far. in order to raise this event you have to set [`WorkerReportsProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`  To make it works You have to assign the EeventHandler of Progress changed, which can be done through:

```
 worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
 worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

And the you can call the following method to trigger the Progress changed event:

```
worker.ReportProgress(intPercent);// intPercent is an integer denotes the percentage
```

Comment: Argh I was looking at the wrong place the whole time. Thanks for your answer. However I get the following error when trying to ReportProgress: "This Background worker states that it doesn't report progress.".

Comment: @Harry: add `worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;` along with the initialization, see the updates

Comment: Thanks for the help I figured it out.